# Run RobotFramework tests with Sikuli Library with Jenkins on VM (RDC)

Tags: jenkins, virtual-machine, robotframework, sikuli, xserver

I have automation tests based on RobotFramework with SikuliLibrary, which are for Image Compare. I'm using Jenkins to run on external server (VM) the tests.
If I open the VM - image compare script works. The screenshot is created.

If I close the VM session and run the test, there is problem. Here is the log from keyword "Get Match Score":

`INFO Could not find C:\Images\image.png
INFO    ${scoreFromImage} = 0.0`

Is look like, when the VM session is not active (opened), "Get Match Score" cannot take a snapshot from the browser for comparing.

Is there any idea, how to fix this?

The Code:

`Compare Process Diagram Image
        [Arguments]   ${ImageName}  ${ImageScore}
    ${scoreFromImage} =  Get Match Score     ${ImagesDirectory}${ImageName}.png
    ${scoreToString} =  Convert To String  ${scoreFromImage}
    ${scoreNumberPrecision} =  Get Substring  ${scoreToString}      0   6
    Run Keyword If  ${scoreNumberPrecision} == ${ImageScore}        Log        Successful       ELSE        Log Fail`

Comment: I think the interesting part is not so much RF and the `Get Match Score` but the code which creates the snapshot. Do you use RF with selenium2library and have you tried to use Xvfb in your Jenkins job?

Comment: Yes, I'm using with selenium2library and the keyword, which create snapshot is `SikuliLibrary.Get Match Score`. About Jenkins and Xvfb - Nope, I didn't try.

Comment: Then I would give it a try: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin   No screenshot without screen, sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Ahh, now there is new problem: 'System is not Unix, Xvfb will not be started'. I'm using Windows.

Comment: I guess this depends on how your Jenkins slave is attached. If as a Windows Service there is a setting to allow the access to the Desktop or run the service as a particular user. This might help.

Comment: Yes, I have service, which is `Jenkins Slave at C:\hudson`. You mean I have to configure in tab "Log on"? Currently is checked: `Local System Account -> Allow service to interact with desktop.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

The VM must be not closed by "X" button. The correct way:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302801
I have .bat file, which contains `tscon.exe %SESSIONNAME% /dest:console`, after run - the VM is closed correctly.
Also "Jenkins slave jar" must be running.

Answer (score 0):

Running Sikuli Test on VM is possible but need to keep session open. We cannot run Sikuli script on locked PC. When you close VM , it get locked and Test fail to run. Sikuli needs images for comparing and clicking, if session is locked there are no images so Test fail to run.
So how we overcome this ? : 
https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/85926/

refer this URL for setting . By applying this you can run sikuli Test with minimized window of VM. (Still you cannot close WM window)

Comment: Hmm, good point, but yeah - I still cannot use the test, when my VM is closed.

Comment: I found solution, the answer is below :)